# Convert large hexadecimal string to octal string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i convert a value given as a hexadecimal string to an Octal format, when the number is too large to fit in a 64 bits number?

I currently convert a byte array to hex like this

```
Byte[] data = { 116, 4, 228, 18, 189, 145, 31, 7, 123, 74, 174, 151, 54, 144, 224, 49, 210, 169, 43, 213 };
hex = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Output in Hex:

```
7404E412BD911F077B4AAE973690E031D2A92BD5
```

How do I get the Octal representation?

So i tried this earlier, but it doesn't work.

```
string binaryval = "";


  binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexValue,16), 8);

    foreach (char ch in hexValue)
    {

           binaryval += Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString(), 16), 8);

    }
```

Comment: Note that your number is too long for an Int32 (max 0xFFFFFFFF), and even Int64 (max 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF). So, the below solutions won't work...

Comment: yes exactly so i was looking for the solution

Comment: @user175084 - If you have to use a value larger then the Int64 structure then you will have to create your own.  The simplest solution would be to handle them as two seperate values that can fit within an Int64 and simply combine the two strings together.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes that is good idea. i was taking 2 items and converting to octal and then combining all together. Thanks

Comment: @user175084 that won't be enough. Because `0xFF` is `0377` (octal), you'll need to do more than taking two characters and converting them.

Comment: so i get this value: Octal value:
164434422275221377173112256227662203406132225153325   please can you verify this value? Thanks a ton.

Comment: @user175084 it seems you have missed my post. The number you mention is _incorrect_. Check my post (or my comment here) to see how you can get the correct value. Try typing `2BD5` in Windows Calc, you'll see `25725`. This is not equal to your `53325`. Remember, three hex nibbles (FFF) equal four octal nibbles (7777). You tried it with two nibbles (FF) which leave you a rest value (377).

Comment: @user175084 there's some unclarity as to what you ask here. You accepted an answer that uses a byte-by-byte approach, and you removed `PadLeft()`, which makes the octal representation unreadable and irreversible (i.e., it is impossible to find out what bytes it represents). Is this really what you are after, or would you want the same as Windows Calc, or http://calc.50x.eu/ shows us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Byte[] data = { 116, 4, 228, 18, 189, 145, 31, 7, 123, 74, 174, 151, 54, 144, 224, 49, 210, 169, 43, 213};
var str = String.Join("", data.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b,8).PadLeft(3,'0')));
```

-

```
//First hex string to byte array
string hex = "7404E412BD911F077B4AAE973690E031D2A92BD5";
List<byte> buf = new List<byte>();
for (int i = 0; i< hex.Length / 2; i++) 
     buf.Add(Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16));

//Then to octal as above
var str = String.Join("", buf.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b,8).PadLeft(3,'0')));
```

Comment: This converts the bytes to an octal string. But `{ 43, 213}` is `0x2BD5`, is octal `25725`, but your solution gives `053325` (see http://calc.50x.eu/).

Comment: hey guys please don't go this way.. I want to convert Hex to octal.. that byte array is just for my testing. Thanks @Able you are right.

Comment: @Abel It works just like `BitConverter.ToString`(Which takes bytes one by one and convert to hex). What you do is converting the byte array to int then getting octal form of it. This aproach wouldn't work if your byte array's length is say 100.

Comment: The problem is that two nibbles don't add up to three octal numbers. FF is 377, not 777. When you take three nibbles, then FFF is 7777.

Comment: i get an error message for above: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]' at this line var str = String.Join("", buf.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b,8).PadLeft(3,'0')));

Comment: @Abel, nothing new. What do you want me to do? voteup your answer which doesn't  take byte order (LSB or MSB)into consideration. Maybe a hex string`FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01` should be converted into `0x01FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` depending on the represantation.

Comment: @user175084 you may try `String.Join("", buf.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 8).PadLeft(3, '0')).ToArray())` . My guess String.Join excepted IEnumerable as argument is new with .Net 4.0

Comment: @user175084 if you remove `PadLeft` you will get `164434422275221377173112256227662203406132225153325` as you commented. But you won't be able to parse it back to byte array.

Comment: Byte order is not relevant, we're using strings. The user @user175084 wanted an octal representation of the number. Not a conversion of each byte into a three-digit octal number, that's simply not how x-based conversions work. You can verify that your answer is incorrect by typing it into Windows Calc (it will show you that `2BD5` equals `25725`, not `53325`). The correct answer for the input is `72004710112754421740736645256456332207003072252225725`.

Comment: In case my point is still unclear, consider converting `2BD5` into decimal, which is `11221`. Taking your approach for octal and translate it to decimal, the outcome would be `043213` instead. It's a common mistake to think in bytes when converting between numbering systems, but the thing is, not all numbering systems fit easily in bytes.

Comment: @Abel you still don't see the point. for ex, `int i = 0x11223344; var s1 = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i)).Replace("-", ""); var s2 = Convert.ToString(i, 16);` you assume hex form comes from `s2`, but It could also be `s1` (and most probably,  when dealing with sizes more than 8 bytes (`long`)).  See  also my previous comment about longlongint `0x01FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Well, you give a representation byte-for-byte in octal representation. If that is what the OP wants, who am I to complain. But considering the example the OP gave with using Convert.XXX, and considering the other answers on the same path, plus considering X-based numbers in general, it seems unlikely. But you're are right, you _do_ give a representation of individual bytes in octal notation, it's just not common and it has little to do with X-based large _numbers_. Hopefully the OP @user175084 sheds some light on what (s)he wanted in the first place.

Comment: Mmm, all things considering, the OP @user175084 removed the `.PadLeft()` on your request. This makes it _impossible_ to get the correct decimal or hexadecimal value back from the octal 'representation'. I really doubt that an irreversible and incomprehensible conversion is what's asked here...

Comment: No i kept the .PadLeft and used the result given by L.B and it worked for me.

Comment: @user175084 good that you kept the PadLeft, at least it is roundtrip conversible. However, I hope you understand that this is _not_ an octal based number, but your own specialistic method of representing the number, leaving many bits unset (i.e., every third digit from the right will never be higher than `3` and the number will occupy more space than it needs to). If that's what you're after, I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the following [link on how to convert hex to decimal, octal or binary](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/09/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-number-to-decimal-octal-and-binary-number-using-c/). It comes with complete code examples:

```
/// <summary>
/// Hex2s the octal.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hexvalue">The hexvalue.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string hex2Octal(string hexvalue)
{
   string binaryval = "";
   binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexvalue, 16), 8);
   return binaryval;
}
```

Comment: I had already looked at this.. but i keep getting errors for the hex value i have in the example.. please can you check.. thanks

Comment: @user175084 - The code supplied does exactly what it should do.  The code is actually the answer to your question.  You simple have an entirely seperate problem the value you are trying to convert is to large for an Int64 which is a problem.

Comment: @user175084 you get errors because your hexvalue is too large. There are currently a couple of solutions that should work with arbitrary length hex values, have a look (but they borrow from this solution as well).

Answer (score 3):

This is not that hard. You should have googled for it before :)
Try this method:

```
public static string hex2Octal(string hexvalue)
   {
      string binaryval = "";
      binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexvalue, 16), 8);
      return binaryval;
   }
```

Comment: hahaha....seems Gaz found it before me.... ;) But hope that your problem is solved. @user

Comment: Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.

Comment: @user175084 - Please update your question to explain your "non-parsable" character comment.

Comment: look we can't figure out your problem unless we see your some kind of log or exception or error that's shown in your console.Show it here. At least show us the input you have given which caused error and the details of the error.

Comment: I wonder why they did not implement it for any base. The docs say the base must be 2, 8, 10 or 16

Comment: @user175084: try using `int.TryParse`, which shows whether the string is convertable to a number. Obviously, your number must be a string of _only_ [0-9a-fA-F] (your original number in your q. is too large anyway, to be converted this way, you may need another solution)

Comment: Thanks Able i know you are right. i am trying to look for a solution

Comment: @user175084 - We cannot help you unless you atempt to do this on your own or at the very least give us an example input and output.

Comment: @Ramhound: i have given you an example on top. what do you need?? 7404E412BD911F077B4AAE973690E031D2A92BD5 is the hex value and i want to convert to octal

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you start off with a hexadecimal string of an arbitrary length, I think the best you can do is take each three bytes and convert them, because `0xFFFFFF` is exactly `77777777` octal (with one or two bytes you have to do more calculation, so this is simply the easiest approach).

```
string hex = "7404E412BD911F077B4AAE973690E031D2A92BD5";
string octal = "";

for (int i = hex.Length; i > 0; i -= 6)
{
    string threebyte;
    if (i < 6)
        threebyte = hex.Substring(0, hex.Length % 6);
    else
        threebyte = hex.Substring(i - 6, 6);

    octal = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(threebyte, 16), 8) + octal;
}
```

This will give you the following correct octal result:

```
72004710112754421740736645256456332207003072252225725
```

You can verify this result easily by taking a smaller number and comparing the least-significant part of the outcome when you type it in Windows Calculator (which can convert from Hex to Oct when you select View > Programmer, or <kbd>Alt-3</kbd>). I.e., when you take `A92BD5` Windows Calculator shows `52225725` as outcome, equal to the above.

The reason that you cannot simply concatenate the results of converting each byte, or each four bytes (int), is that only one and a half byte fits in two octals (`FFF` equals `7777`, but the range `00-FF` fits in `000-377`), or three bytes fit in four octals (`FFFFFF` equals `77777777`). Which is why I chose to split on six digits in my approach.

Comment: i thought the answer was  Octal value: 164434422275221377173112256227662203406132225153325 please can you verify this value?? thanks a lot man

Comment: @user175084: your answer is incorrect. See my response to your earlier comment under the question. Just type the last four hex digits in Windows Calc, that should be enough proof to you and also show you that my answer is the correct one. If you need more explanation as to why, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem. You are sending a hexvalue to the aforesaid method,something like 0A45D and when Convert.ToInt32 method is getting that value it's failing to parse. And again your values are larger for an Int32 structure.
**So simply take your number(the hex representation), split it into 2 smaller string using any technique and then pass them separately to the above method.Get the strings and add them up.**
Something like following:

```
public static string BigHexToOct(string number)
{
    string a= "first splitted part from number";
    string b= "second splitted part from number";
    string result= this.hex2Octal(a)+this.hex2Octal(b);
    return result;

}
```

Try it and let us know.

You can try this way ; take a small part of your given string at first , see if it's converted successfully. If it is, then increase the length of string that the `hex2octal` method can convert successfully and this way you will know how you can divide your big number string.

Comment: This would only work if you first split the string into correct parts (you write "using any technique", but it should be, cut them up from the right side, in parts divisible by three or six), otherwise just concatenating will give you incorrect values.